# Can I request a deleted question be migrated?

Tags: support, migration, deleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707/how-do-you-track-your-hours was a pretty popular question. I understand it's not programming related, but it's a common problem for programmers. Is it possible to request migrating it to programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: It won't fly on Programmers.  Let me see if I can get permission to migrate it to the new Productivity.SE site.